# Why i am getting this error while installing angular cli?

Tags: npm, installation, angular-cli

I've input the following lines:

```
C:\Users\Surendra>node -v
v8.11.4

C:\Users\Surendra>npm -v
5.6.0

C:\Users\Surendra>npm install -g @angular/cli
```

and I'm getting the following error:

```
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcli failed, reason: Hostname/IP doesn't match certificate's altnames: "Host: registry.npmjs.org. is not in the cert's altnames: DNS:a.sni.fastly.net, DNS:a.sni.global-ssl.fastly.net"

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Surendra\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-09-01T15_14_45_954Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

`run npm cache clean --force` and `npm install npm -g`

after that try to run `npm config set strict-ssl false`

if it doesn't work try to run `npm config set registry "http://registry.npmjs.org"`

**Edit:**

> An earlier outage involving a DNS misconfiguration has lead to some ISPs caching npmjs.com as missing, a workaround for this is to use a third party DNS provider such as Cloudflare or Google, the affected caches should clear within the next 24 hours.

https://status.npmjs.org/incidents/v22ffls5cd6h

Comment: ok.. but i have downloaded the latest version from internet of nodejs today itself and it is showing 5.6.0 .. i dont think it is old.. let me try the commands that u have shared.

Comment: Yes it works .. the latest version of npm is showing as 6.4.1 thanks alot.